# DAX CALCULATE() doesn't seem to be overriding pivot filter

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I am learning to use Power Pivot and write DAX and I am working through a book I bought written by Rob Collie and Avichal Singh called "Power Pivot and Power BI".

Early on it explains what happens when using CALCULATE() in a measure. A key point of understanding is explained as follows:

> If a filter argument acts on a column that IS already on the pivot, it
>   will **override** the pivot context for that column

So in a simple table called "GSR" I have a series of invoices with an invoice date, a product and an amount. I have another column that converts all invoice dates to the last day of the month to gather them together. I have created a measure called "Total orders" that is counting the number of rows.

I have created a pivot of this data with:

- Products in the rows
- Month end in the columns (but I've actually chosen Month and Year from the automatic breakdown Power Pivot has done on my Month_End column)
- Orders in the values

This pivot renders correctly.

Now the issue:

I've created two slicers that are feeding off two disconnected tables; one containing month numbers, and one containing years. Based on the selection from each of these I have a measure that creates a month end using the EOMONTH(DATE(),0). This measure is called "Comparison_Month_End".

I then have another measure called "Compare_Orders" that contains the following:

```
CALCULATE([Total orders],FILTER(GSR,GSR[Month_End]=[Comparison_Month_End]))
```

The point of all of this - this is meant to get the orders from the GSR where the month and year match the slicer selection. I want this value to appear in the pivot for every month selected i.e. not filtered by the pivot.

It doesn't work, however. This seems to me to be counter to what the book says, which is that if the filter in the measure is applied to a column on the pivot (in this case Month_End), the pivot filter is overriden. So, for example, if I have 31-Mar-18 in a column on my pivot and the comparison month end is 31-Jan-18, I would expect to see the January orders within "Compare_Orders" sitting next to the March orders, the February orders, the December orders and so on, but it only appears next to January.

[image]

To me this is doing exactly the same as an example in the book where there is a pivot with Year in the rows, Total Sales in column 1 and then 2002 sales in column 2. Column 1 shows sales for each year, column 2 shows the same sales figure (i.e. 2002 sales) against every row, even where the row year is 2001, 2003 or 2004. The 2002 Sales measure is using CALCULATE() summing Total Sales, filtering on "Sales[Year] = 2002".

[image]

Could anyone please explain why what I expected to happen doesn't seem to be happening please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CALCULATE` does indeed override the filter context when evaluating its first argument; using the rows provided to its second argument as the new filter context. However; `CALCULATE` does not alter the filter context when evaluating its second argument, and so pre-existing filters remain unless they are explicitly removed.

In `FILTER(GSR,GSR[Month_End]=[Comparison_Month_End])`, `FILTER` only iterates over rows of `GSR` that are present in the pre-existing filter context (the pivot context). To get all rows, use `ALL`:

```
CALCULATE([Total orders],FILTER(ALL(GSR),GSR[Month_End]=[Comparison_Month_End]))
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for replying. I did also try this but this then returned all orders in January for all product types. The filter on products on each row then doesn’t seem to apply.

Comment: I suppose my main question actually is still how the book manages to achieve the output shown in the example without requiring ALL() in their 2002 Sales measure. On the 2001 row the table being acted upon must be filtered to only include 2001 rows, so there shouldn’t be any 2002 sales in it and therefore should return a blank like the orders do in my example?? I suppose the only difference between my example and theirs is that they aren’t using FILTER() and have “Sales[Year]=2002” as the second CALCULATE() argument.

Comment: @mickeyt: I'm guessing your book has `CALCULATE('Sales'[Total], 'Sales'[Year]=2002)`. When the second argument of `CALCULATE` is a boolean filter rather than a table of values, it is equivalent to `FILTER(ALL(column), filter)`: that is: `CALCULATE('Sales'[Total], FILTER(ALL('Sales'[Year]), 'Sales'[Year]=2002))`. I'd recommend reading Chapter 5 of [The Definitive Guide to DAX](https://www.sqlbi.com/books/the-definitive-guide-to-dax/), which goes through these examples in detail.

Comment: @mickeyt: The reason that the example in my answer overrides all filters on the `GSR` table is that the second argument to `CALCULATE` includes all columns from the `GSR` table. If you want it to just override the filter on a specific column, write it as `CALCULATE([Total orders],FILTER(ALL(GSR[Month_End]),GSR[Month_End]=[Comparison_Month_End]))`; this will leave the other columns intact, as the second argument to `CALCULATE` will now only include a single column.

Comment: HI again. Thank you - I get it now: "When the second argument of CALCULATE is a boolean filter rather than a table of values, it is equivalent to FILTER(ALL(column), filter): that is: CALCULATE('Sales'[Total], FILTER(ALL('Sales'[Year]), 'Sales'[Year]=2002))". Perhaps I missed this subtle point in the book but I'm clear now. I've tried the measure both ways and it works. The only thing, however, is that when using FILTER(), it still doesn't work if I use "Month" and "Year" rather than "Month_End" if "Month_End" is used in ALL() in the measure. I get why but need to be careful with dates clearly